# Embeded swf file to Content asp.net page

Tags: asp.net, flash

Greeting,
have a swf file which content a FlvPlayback play to play targeted video.
It is working OK when I run published HTML file from flash professional CS5.

but when I embedded this flash to asp.net content page using   object tag the move will pay but the video controls play and stop with disappear.

I listed down the code I sued.

Please advice.

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Master.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Home.aspx.cs" Inherits="HabibWebSite.Home" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <object width="700" height="700">

  <embed src="Flash/FlashPlayer.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="700" height="700"></embed>

</object>


</asp:Content>
```

---

### Update

The swf file is depend on other files such as skin file, image, video each...

these file are on same folder where is my swf file located and they are all under one folder my my VS2010 project. When I run the swf file from the folder in the VS2010 project is working OK but when I embed it to aspx page I will miss some controls in the flash.
I tried another swf file that depend on external resource to run such as xml file, and images, jscript fie and the swf file will lunch but will not work and there is no images would appear but still when I run the swf file from the VS2010 project will run OK.

I'm listing down the following :

1-html code for the htlm file generated by flash professional CS5 to lunch the flash in  browser.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>FlashPlayer</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <style type="text/css" media="screen">
        html, body { height:100%; background-color: #ffffff;}
        body { margin:0; padding:0; overflow:hidden; }
        #flashContent { width:100%; height:100%; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="flashContent">

            <object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" width="473" height="269" id="FlashPlayer" align="middle">
                <param name="movie" value="FlashPlayer.swf" />
                <param name="quality" value="high" />
                <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />
                <param name="play" value="true" />
                <param name="loop" value="true" />
                <param name="wmode" value="window" />
                <param name="scale" value="showall" />
                <param name="menu" value="true" />

                <param name="devicefont" value="false" />
                <param name="salign" value="" />
                <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
                <!--[if !IE]>-->
                <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="FlashPlayer.swf" width="473" height="269">
                    <param name="movie" value="FlashPlayer.swf" />
                    <param name="quality" value="high" />
                    <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />
                    <param name="play" value="true" />

                    <param name="loop" value="true" />
                    <param name="wmode" value="window" />
                    <param name="scale" value="showall" />
                    <param name="menu" value="true" />
                    <param name="devicefont" value="false" />
                    <param name="salign" value="" />
                    <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
                <!--<![endif]-->
                    <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflash">

                        <img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" />
                    </a>
                <!--[if !IE]>-->
                </object>
                <!--<![endif]-->
            </object>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

2-the code I used to lunch the swf file with aspx.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="HabibWebSite.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <style type="text/css" media="screen">
        html, body { height:100%; background-color: #ffffff;}
        body { margin:0; padding:0; overflow:hidden; }
        #flashContent { width:100%; height:100%; }
        </style>


</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="flashContent">

            <object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" width="473" height="269" id="FlashPlayer" align="middle">
                <param name="movie" value="Flash/FlashPlayer/FlashPlayer.swf" />
                <param name="quality" value="high" />
                <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />
                <param name="play" value="true" />
                <param name="loop" value="true" />
                <param name="wmode" value="window" />
                <param name="scale" value="showall" />
                <param name="menu" value="true" />

                <param name="devicefont" value="false" />
                <param name="salign" value="" />
                <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
                <!--[if !IE]>-->
                <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="Flash/FlashPlayer/FlashPlayer.swf" width="473" height="269">
                    <param name="movie" value="Flash/FlashPlayer/FlashPlayer.swf" />
                    <param name="quality" value="high" />
                    <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />
                    <param name="play" value="true" />

                    <param name="loop" value="true" />
                    <param name="wmode" value="window" />
                    <param name="scale" value="showall" />
                    <param name="menu" value="true" />
                    <param name="devicefont" value="false" />
                    <param name="salign" value="" />
                    <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
                <!--<![endif]-->
                    <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflash">

                        <img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" />
                    </a>
                <!--[if !IE]>-->
                </object>
                <!--<![endif]-->
            </object>
        </div>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

3-html code generated when lunch the aspx page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><title>

</title><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <style type="text/css" media="screen">
        html, body { height:100%; background-color: #ffffff;}
        body { margin:0; padding:0; overflow:hidden; }
        #flashContent { width:100%; height:100%; }
        </style>


</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="WebForm1.aspx" id="form1">
<div class="aspNetHidden">

<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwUJNjI2MjY0OTg0ZGS7bT2BP5w5OjKaeICJTgBmmuzIKMGdB9pFIMPQCLbAiw==" />
</div>

    <div id="flashContent">

            <object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" width="473" height="269" id="FlashPlayer" align="middle">
                <param name="movie" value="Flash/FlashPlayer/FlashPlayer.swf" />
                <param name="quality" value="high" />
                <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />
                <param name="play" value="true" />
                <param name="loop" value="true" />

                <param name="wmode" value="window" />
                <param name="scale" value="showall" />
                <param name="menu" value="true" />

                <param name="devicefont" value="false" />
                <param name="salign" value="" />
                <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
                <!--[if !IE]>-->
                <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="Flash/FlashPlayer/FlashPlayer.swf" width="473" height="269">

                    <param name="movie" value="Flash/FlashPlayer/FlashPlayer.swf" />
                    <param name="quality" value="high" />
                    <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />
                    <param name="play" value="true" />

                    <param name="loop" value="true" />
                    <param name="wmode" value="window" />
                    <param name="scale" value="showall" />
                    <param name="menu" value="true" />

                    <param name="devicefont" value="false" />
                    <param name="salign" value="" />
                    <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
                <!--<![endif]-->
                    <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflash">

                        <img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" />
                    </a>
                <!--[if !IE]>-->

                </object>
                <!--<![endif]-->
            </object>
        </div>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you showing the complete  and  tags you're using? This will not work in all browsers.

ASP.NET pre se is not doing anything be producing an html page that contains the html markup you specify. So I suggest creating a static html page and embedding your player in there and make sure things work as you expect. Once you have your html page (and the markup) working the way you expect, you can copy the  tag and paste it into your aspx page.

Comment: @Shiv Kumar Thank you for your help. As I said the swf file working OK with html file and when I pasted the html code to my aspx page I will have a problem and I tried this with  other swf files. so the tags would work with html file but not with aspx also I tested that web firefox brwoser and IE and getting same result.

Comment: @Eyla, ok, then what is the difference between the two html markups? That is have you looked at the html generated by the .aspx page (do a view source in the browser). If there is no difference, then there should be no difference in the behavior. If there is a difference, please post both, the working html (the bare minimum complete html) as well as the non-working on. If your swf files relies on certain urls for the videos and other assets such as images, please also mention that. And finally, what in your swf code will make the controls disappear?

Comment: Note that ASP.NET is not making the controls in your swf disappear. ASP.NET pre se does not control nor have initmate knowledge of your swf file.

Comment: @Shiv Kumar I would appreciate if you would see my update on the post and give my your comments.

Comment: @Eyla, you issue seems to be an url issue. Please understand that this is nothing to do with .aspx or ASP.NET. If you swf looking for these other files using a file path or a url? Here is what you need to try: Instead of "running" your swf from a folder. Try browsing to it using a browser. That is use a Url to browser to your swf file rather than a file path such as C:\somefolder\flash etc. You issue is really a Flash related issue and not an ASP.NET related issue. You need to understand how to develop your Flash swf application using urls instead of file paths.

Comment: @Shiv Kumar Thank you for your help. I think I found out where is the problem now. I need to find a way how I should embed the swf file and its related file such the skin swf file.